# Getting Vagrant to work with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm new to both Vagrant and AWS but trying to get the two to play together.

I'm following the instructions [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws), but something doesn't seem correct.

So far my steps are :

1. List item
2. Log into AWS Console
3. Go into IAM
4. Create user vagrant_test
5. Downloaded credentials.csv
6. Edit user vagrant_test
   Attach policies :
7. AmazonRDSFullAccess
8. AmazonEC2FullAccess
9. AmazonS3FullAccess
10. AmazonRoute53FullAccess
11. Go to Services -> EC2
12. Create Key Pair called vagrant_kp
13. Download vagrant_kp.pem
14. Install Vagrant on local machine
    vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
15. Add the dummy box
    vagrant box add dummy https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box
16. Check to see if box is installed
    $ vagrant box list
    dummy (aws, 0)
17. Create Vagrantfile with contents

    ```
    Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
      config.vm.box = "dummy"

      config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
      aws.access_key_id = "<hidden>"
      aws.secret_access_key = "<hidden>"
      aws.keypair_name = "vagrant_kp"
      aws.ami = "ami-52978200"
      #Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09 (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-52978200
      override.ssh.username = "ec2-user"
      override.ssh.private_key_path = "/Users/delOne/Test/re/aws/vagrant_kp.pem"

      end

    end
    ```

Now whenever I run Vagrant as `vagrant up —-provider=aws`, I always get the following message:

> The machine with the name '`—-provider=aws`' was not found configured for this Vagrant environment.

Now I'm not sure what's causing that message.

Would anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

you would need to add the [vagrant-aws plugin](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws)

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

then you can run

```
vagrant up --provider=aws
```

If you already had installed the plugin, try to uninstall first and reinstall

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-aws 
vagrant plugin install vagrant-aws
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have made any difference to me - I have added the dummy box and installed the plugin. Is there any other reason why one might be getting this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with
***vagrant up —-provider=aws***

I ended up doing this:

```
export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=aws
vagrant up
```